# How to get url value another page in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How to pass url data another page, I am creating simple component I want to send href value another page because need to send  dynamic values (i.e) I added link value  to send **store/[storeId]** page. I need get number values from this link . How to get could you please solve this Issues

MenuApi.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { Grid, Image } from "semantic-ui-react";
import Link from 'next/link';
 function MenuApi(props) {
   return (
    
         <Grid className="home-icon">
      
      <Grid.Row centered doubling columns={8} mobile>
        {props.menu.map((x, i) => (
          <Grid.Column centered key={i} Style="width: 9%!important;"> 
            <Link href="category/fitness/25">
              <Image src={x.image} alt=""/>
            </Link> 
            <Link href="category/fitness/25">
              <p >{x.store_name}</p>
            </Link>
          </Grid.Column>
        ))}
      </Grid.Row>
    </Grid>
    
   )
 }

export default MenuApi;
```

store/[storeId].js

```
import {useRouter} from 'next/router';
function Store()
{
    const router=useRouter();
    const route=router.query.storId;
    return(
        <h1>Store{route}</h1>
    )
}
export default Store;
```

Comment: So basically in the provided example you want to get the value 25 in `router.query.storId`?

Comment: Yes, I want to get 25 value.

Comment: check useParams method and template literals to your href attribute. Also, it's I'm not sure about nextjs but it's more appropraite to use `to` instead of href

Comment: fitness/25, fitness and 25 dynamic value, once click link redirect http://localhost:3000/category/fitness/25,

Comment: Could your problem be the typo in `router.query.storId` Shouldn't it be `router.query.storeId`?

Comment: @karthik If both `fitness` and `25` are dynamic, then your route should either be `/category/[category]/[id]`, OR a catch-all route `/category/[...params]`. Either way, how does `store/[storeId]` route fit into all this?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your questions correctly this should work for you

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Post = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { storeId } = router.query

  return <p>Post: {storeId}</p>
}

export default Post
```

Any route like `/fitness/1`, `/fitness/abc`, etc. will be matched by pages/post/[storeId].js. The matched path parameter will be sent as a query parameter to the page, and it will be merged with the other query parameters.

For example, the route `/fitness/abc` will have the following query object:

```
{ "storeId": "abc" }
```

Similarly, the route /fitness/abc?foo=bar will have the following query object:

```
{ "foo": "bar", "storeId": "abc" }
```

Comment: His file is named *store/[storeId].js*. So the parameter won't be named `pid` but `storeId`.

Comment: thanks gentleman working fine one more thing 'fitness, automotive' also dynamic, howto change dynamic